# Is possible to make inheritance in this xml using jaxb?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to know if is possible to create a abstract class `adress` to using with `job` and `home` tags?

Like in this code

```
<person>
  <home>
    <adress>
      <street>marte</street>
      <number>200</number>
    </adress>
  </home>
  <job>
    <adress>
      <street>saint loius</street>
      <number>100</number>
    </adress>
  </job>
</person>
```

If is possible, can someome show me a example code...

Comment: Why would you want it to be `abstract`?

Comment: Did you try to code yourself first? Show us some code?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i thougth it was good for the code, but i can be `concrete class`

Comment: @NarendraPathai

`@XmlSeeAlso({ AdressHome.class, AdressJob.class })
public abstract class Adress {

 @XmlElement(name = "street")
 private String street;
 @XmlElement(name = "number")
 private String number;
 
 //getter and setter

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "home")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AdressHome extends Adress {

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "job")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AdressJob extends Adress {

}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the interface class...

I didn´t put annotation to map the fields

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by leveraging the `@XmlElementRef` annotation on a property in which the type is the common super class.  Then annotate each subclass with the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html